# Exact link of vertical tabs

Tags: forms

I am using [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group).

With 2 Vertical Tab, '**Step 1**' and '**Step 2**'.

I want to put a link "**NEXT**" on '**Step 1**' that should open '**Step 2**', same a back link on '**Step 2**' that should go back to '**Step 1**'.
[image]

I tried different combinations with **Multipage** but did not work here. How can I do this? I can put text but I don't know how to get the link of the other tabs directly.

Comment: As far as i remember, there is no such thing as  "link to tab", because Field Group's tabs are just like Form API vertical tabs: on one page, and switching them happens with JavaScript. If so, you need to script your "next" and "previous" links to switch tabs, and in that case URL in these links does not really matter anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the ID of the pane (fieldset) to the URL as a fragment, e.g.

```
http://example.com/node/[ID]/edit#edit-metatags
```

Assuming metatag is installed, that code will open the metatags tab directly on page load.

An example for core might be:

```
http://example.com/node/[ID]/edit#edit-options
```

For the "Publishing options" tab.